# Is there a way to obtain a Dell server's RAID configuration/level using only winrm/wsman? (ESXi servers)

Tags: raid, dell, winrm, uri

I've seen videos describing how to configure RAID using wsman/winrm commands run against a server's iDRAC, but I can't seem to find anything that will just give me the current configuration and RAID levels. Is this possible? What uri would I use? If it matters, this is being run against M610s.

Edit: If there is an easier way to obtain this information by running a script against the iDRAC, I'm not opposed to switching my methods.

**EDIT: The server is running ESXi, so if there is a way to obtain this through the vSphere client or PowerCLI, I can do that too. Overall, I just need a way to obtain the RAID configuration for multiple servers without having to query against the actual server (eg: via the iDRAC).**

Comment: usually not but if you have the dell management pack installed you'll see a custome wmi class that you can see this info with.

Comment: @tonyroth Can I script against that wmi class remotely, or will I need to log onto the server? Also, would I still be scripting against the iDRAC? The servers are actually running Linux, so that might cause some problems.

Comment: yes you can script against the class remotely

Comment: sorry didn't know this was linux, not sure if there is a completely working ws-man process for linux yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell doc Lifecycle_Controller_2_0_Web_Services_Interface_Guide_for_Linux_v1.1.pdf has what you are looking for:
wsman enumerate http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/root/dcim/DCIM_ControllerView -h $IPADDRESS -V -v -c dummy.cert -P 443 -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD -j utf-8 -y basic

Be warned though - Dell utterly sucks at documenting the WSMAN arch for Linux.  Such fun things as:

RAIDLevel:
RAID 0 = 2
RAID 1 = 4 
RAID 5 = 64
RAID 6 = 128

You want RAID 5? - you have to request "64" (a value they put into the controller - WHY they can't use the standard numbers is yours to discover).  Have tried to find a way to configure more then one volume on a single system in one command and have yet to get help, find any information, or know the special tag needed (if available) to work.  Good luck.